# Rails, Devise & Omniauth - See what's in env["omniauth.auth"]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I've set up a rails project using devise and omniauth-facebook. It works but I can only access certain information using `user.email =auth.info.email || ""` etc.

I'm pretty new to this, especially JSON so I'm wondering is there a quick and easy way to see exactly what `env["omniauth.auth"]` is returning in the callback?

I've been at this for hours. Sorry if I haven't provided enough information.

Answer (score 0):

I can use `puts env["omniauth.auth"]` to show me exactly what's in the hash